# Lorentz invariance of the Dirac equation and implicability of the Klein-Gordon equation from the Dirac equation

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, group-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am reading the Peskin & Schroeder's Introduction to quantum field theory, p.42~43 and don't understand some points. In their book p.42 they say that

"To show that it (the Dirac equation) is Lorentz invariant, write down the Lorentz-transformed version of the left-hand side (of the Dirac equation) and calculate:
$$[i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m]\psi(x) \to [i\gamma^{\mu}(\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}-m]\Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}\psi(\Lambda^{-1}x) = \cdots,$$
where $$\Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}} := \operatorname{exp}(-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu \nu}S^{\mu \nu})\tag{3.30}$$
(their book p.42)

**Q.1)** And my first question is, why the left-hand side of the Dirac equation is Lorentz - transformed in this fashion?

And, in the page 43, he derives the Klein-Gordon equation from the Dirac equation as following way : by acting on the left with $(-i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)$,

$$ 0= (-i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)(i\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}-m)\psi = (\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} + m^{2})\psi=(\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu} \}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} + m^{2})\psi = (\partial^{2}+m^{2})\psi$$

( $\gamma^{\mu}$ is the *weyl* (*chiral*) representation? )

**Q.2)** My second question is, why the thrid equality is true? $$\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu} \} := \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} + \gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu} = 2\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}~ ?$$ If so, Why?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I will start with the second question. The equality you have written there is not true. The equality
$$\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
with $\eta^{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(+1,-1,-1,-1)$ being the Minkowski metric. As you can see, the $\gamma$ matrices do not commute.

As far as the second question goes, you have to keep in mind that the $\gamma$ matrices do not transform under Lorentz transformations, as they are simply matrices. What does transform, is the differential operator
$$\partial_{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\rightarrow
(\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}$$
and the spinor
$$\psi(x)\rightarrow\Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}\psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$$
You see the spinor transforms both with respect to the internal degrees of freedom (i.e. with \Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}) and with respect to the external ones (i.e with $\Lambda^{-1}$).

Please let me know if there are further questions.

Comment: O.K. Thank you. Can I ask further? First, as you wrote, if $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} + \gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}= 2 \eta^{\mu \nu}$, then we get the Klein-Gordon equation ( the fourth equality in the above calculation in my question). But I still don't know why the third equality is true ; i.e., why $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} = \frac{1}{2} \{ \gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\}$? Second, why the term $\Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}$ appears in the trasformation of $\psi(x)$?

Comment: Yes, ofc. Okay, so, $\gamma^{\mu}$ and $\gamma^{\mu}$ are two 4x4 matrices. So, they do not commute. This means that $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\ne\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}$. Therefore, in the definition of the anti-commutator of two $\gamma$ matrices (or of anything else for that matter) $\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\ne 2\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}$. To validate that, you can google search the exact form of the $\gamma$ matrices and substitute, for instance $\mu=0,\ \nu=1$ to see that $\gamma^0\gamma^1\ne\gamma^1\gamma^0$. Btw, $\mu,\ \nu=0,1,2,3$

Comment: The term $\Lambda_{1/2}$ transforms the spinor components. So, it must be there. $\psi$ is an object that has a number of components (not necessarily as many as the dimensionality of your spacetime) and therefore those components must be transformed as well, just like the spacetime (or momentum) four vectors etc. If there is anything else, please let me know

Comment: Thank you. As you commented, the $\gamma$ matrices do not commute. But I asked that why  $(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} + m^{2})\psi=(\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu} \}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} + m^{2})\psi$ in the above calculation holds :)

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. So, because $\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}=\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}$ (i.e. there is no right order for the derivative to act on the spinor), then one can write $\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}$ (just relabelled some dummy indices in the first step and changed the order of differentiation in the second)

Comment: The term in the parenthesis is the definition of the anti-commutator and from there on, I think you can see what is going on. If there is anything else, please let me know

Comment: O.K. Finally I got it. Thanks for kind explanation ~